# NotSupportedError: Python value of type numpy.int32 not supported. ORACLE DB

Tags: python, oracle

I've created a table inside my oracle DB and I'm using this format that was advised by him for this type of data, I'm in python trying to insert the data in the DB, but this column doesn't accept the data coming from the data frame that is in the `int32` type. If I create the variable with the number a part = 300, it contains the `int` type and the DB accepts it.

What should I change in the table structure inside the DB to accept `int32`?

```sql
set_target            NUMBER(9)
```

table inside DB

```
NotSupportedError: Python value of type numpy.int32 not supported.
```

```python
def convertt(x):
    x = int(x)
    return x

abc = [convertt(x) for  x in a.iloc[0].values if type(x) == int else x]
```

Comment: Don't change the database column, change the python code.

Comment: ok do you have any suggestions ? i keep trying to change the type of the column df["column"].astype(int) and it stays int32

Comment: [Edit] your question and include a [MRE] which is minimal and complete - i.e. it includes sufficient Python code to see how you are `INSERT`ing data into the database. The problem is probably not with your dataframe but with how your dataframe is being used in the `INSERT` and you haven't shared any of that code.